# How to render in real-time one of the fields of the Django model?

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-models, real-time-updates

I already set up the connection between the server side which are the asgi.py, consumers, and routing, that is already listening to client side using javascript. But I don't know how to render out, in real time, the field in that one model to my javascript that'll will be shown in HTML.

I'm not trying anything for now since I do not know where to start, and what to do. But all I want to achieve is to render that one field from the model through the HTML in real time.

Comment: Hint: Look up AJAX or Websockets

Comment: in JavaScript you may have to run `setInterval()` to run periodically function with `fetch(url,..)` to get new data from Python, and with code which replaces data in HTML in browser.

Comment: Can you share what you have done currently with JavaScript? Based on the question, it is only the rendering logic your are struggling with?

Comment: this is what I already done in Javascript:

`var socket = new WebSocket(`ws://${window.location.host}/time/`);

      socket.onmessage = function (e) {
        var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
        document.getElementById("time").innerText = data.message;
      };`